# How to set a property once it has been saved and re-save a child property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

```
factory :user do
  company
  phone "123-123-1234"
  .
  .

end
```

The company model has a property that I need to set also:

```
company.owner_id = -1
```

But I need to set the owner_id to the user's id.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [callback](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks)

```
factory :user do
  company
  phone "123-123-1234"
  .
  .
  after(:create) { |user| user.company.update(owner_id: user.id) }
end
```